# Google Cloud Access Token Expiry

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to the MySQL database with the authentication type gcp_iam_auth.
This requires me to always get a token from GCP via this command `gcloud auth print-access-token`, but the problem is that this token expires after one hour.
So I entered the MySQL Administration and tried to copy the password from my user. I received a forbidden message ( Attached screenshot ).
How can I get this password? Am I connecting the right way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymScU.png

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the password. The system does not know the plain text password either.

The command `gcloud auth print-access-token` is intended for developers to use while writing and testing software and not for long-term use i.e. the token is valid for 3,600 seconds (with default organization settings).

Comment: So how should I connect?

Comment: @AihamAbuRafaa - You need to use Google OAuth. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 If you mean how do you connect without the password, you can either change the password or create another user.

Comment: Can I connect to MySQL via a service account?

Comment: @AihamAbuRafaa - Your original question has been answered. Please do not ask additional questions in the comments section. Post a new question instead.